# Linux shell script nested read

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I am writing a shell script, I have a problem about nested read as the following codes.

```
while read entry
do
    IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$entry"

    read -p "Read from keyboard" keyin

    case $keyin in
       [a]* ) .....
       .....
    esac
done << file
```

I expected to read keyboard input but the 'read -p .... keyin' always read value from 'file'.  Is anyone have idea about this? Any alternative method for me to read keyboard input in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the shell `bash`?  If so, say so (otherwise you might be asking about Korn shell or `zsh` or Dash instead, or as well).  Add the tag and say so in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `bash`, you can arrange to [`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) from different file descriptors:

```
while read -r -u 3 entry
do
    IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$entry"

    read -p "Read from keyboard" keyin

    case $keyin in
       [a]* ) .....
       .....
    esac
done 3< file
```

The [`3<`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input) redirects `file` as input to file descriptor 3; the `-u 3` tells `read` to read from file descriptor 3.  Thus, the outer loop is acting on lines from the file, leaving the inner `read` to act on keyboard input.  The `-r` is modern but necessary to avoid unexpected behaviour (I learned to program without it; I resent needing to use it — the flag should be necessary to enable the modified behaviour).

Note that the original code in the question used `<< file`; that starts a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), but clearly wasn't what was intended since no body or end of the here document was shown.